# Alter Table Move command - ORACLE

Tags: oracle11g, alter-table, tablespace

Consider i have TABLE1 in Tablespace TS1. I have another Tablespace TS2.

What is the difference between the below three

1. ALTER TABLE TABLE1 MOVE NOLOGGING PARALLEL;
2. ALTER TABLE TABLE1 MOVE TABLESPACE TS1 NOLOGGING PARALLEL;
3. ALTER TABLE TABLE1 MOVE TABLESPACE TS2 NOLOGGING PARALLEL;

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Database SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_3001.htm#i2085301):

> The `move_table_clause` lets you relocate data of a nonpartitioned table or of a partition of a partitioned table into a new segment, optionally in a different tablespace, and optionally modify any of its storage attributes.

Therefore, with your first statement Oracle will move the table to a new segment on the same tablespace, while in the other two statements Oracle will move the table to a new segment on the specified tablespace (respectively TS1 and TS2).

If `TABLE1` is already on tablespace `TS1` then the first and second command will perform the same action.

Using `MOVE` without changing the tablespace will simply reorganize the segment on the original tablespace.

Comment: Marco.. First one is just move .. Second is move to the same table-space which the table exists.. Third is to move to other table-space.. What is the difference between 1 and 2? Am moved to a new project.. The first one is used in it.. It greatly reduces the space of the table-space after execution.. But want to know how it is different from 2? What is the advantage?

Comment: @GKN I have expanded my answer

Comment: Thanks Marco.. If you have any link on this ..please share.. It will help me very much

Answer (score 0):

I tried many scripts but didn't worked for all objects. You can't move clustered [objects](https://www.orahow.com/2018/06/move-all-objects-to-another-tablespace.html) from one [tablespace](https://www.orahow.com/2018/06/move-all-objects-to-another-tablespace.html) to another, for that you will have to use expdp. So I will suggest expdp is the best option to move all objects to different tablesapce.

Below is the command.

```
nohup expdp \"/ as sysdba\" DIRECTORY=test_dir DUMPFILE=users.dmp LOGFILE=users.log TABLESPACES=USERS &
```

https://www.orahow.com/2018/06/move-all-objects-to-another-tablespace.html